# function ()() in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am not sure how to call/frame this question title, but can anyone explain me what does the below code do?

```
var routes = require("./routes/routes.js")(app);
```

I am seeing a `second ()` with app being passed, what does that do?
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/restful-angularjs-nodejs/blob/master/app.js

To my surprise, in the code above the variable routes is not at all used in app.js? what's the purpose. I am quite confused here does `(app) argument` do anything magic here?

Comment: (1) The routes.js file exports a function so it's immediately invoked and the result stored in `routes`. (2) In that call, the `app` is passed to the router, so app does actually make use of the router, just not of the variable `routes`.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan : app.use("/", require("./routes")); is this code equivalent to above code?

Comment: That could work. I'm not sure. Give it a try.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan: That works, my question is this same as above code? in the above i don't specify any path but here i do with "/"?

Comment: That's what I was responding to. What makes me suspect that this will not work is the async way routes is setup. You give routes your app, it it adds stuff to it. Now, if `app.use` is setup such that it passes a copy of `app` to its second router argument, then I think that might work as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The construct

```
foo()();
```

expects that `foo()` returns a function and calls it immediately. It's equivalent to the more readable:

```
var func = foo();
func();
```

A similar construct you'll often see is:

```
(function() {
    // function definition
})(args);
```

This defines a function and calls it immediately. The primary use is to emulate block scope for variables.

Comment: Can you just do a small fiddle with a basic example on foo()(arg) ?